# if xx or xx, else... condition in dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I would need to provide an `if or..., else` condition inside a dockerfile.
I found a solution for an if, else... But I am not able to include an `or` condition inside the if

This solution works:

```
 RUN if [ condition 1 ] ; then \
         command 1; \
 
 else; then \
     condition 2; fi
```

I have tried something like this, unsuccessfully:

```
 RUN if [ condition 1 | condition 2 ] ; then \
         command 1; \
 
 else; then \
     condition 2; fi
```

How can I add the `or` inside the conditional?

Comment: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47584/in-a-bash-script-using-the-conditional-or-in-an-if-statement) you can find some solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a single Docker `RUN` instruction, you're running a shell command, and any Bourne shell syntax is allowed.  If you're using `[ ... ]` that's actually running [**test**(1)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) which has a `-o` operator for "or".

```sh
RUN if [ condition1 -o condition 2 ]; then \
      command1; \
    else \
      command2; \
    fi
```

The POSIX spec suggests the `-o` option is obsolete, and recommends using the shell `||` operator instead.

```sh
RUN if [ condition1 ] || [ condition2 ]; then ...; fi
RUN if test condition1 || test condition2 ; then ...; fi
```

More generally, Dockerfiles don't support conditionals; you can't conditionally `COPY` a file in, for example.  Conversely, if you are writing complex installation logic, you can write and test an ordinary shell script on the host, `COPY` it into the image, and `RUN` it, which can be easier than trying to remember to backslash-escape every line ending.